# How can I apply "easy" formatting to org-mode blocks?

Tags: html, export, org-mode, markup

Org-mode is great for getting light markup and organization done, and the exporting is great too. However, I'm having trouble getting a simple formatting option done.

I'd like to cast a whole block in monospace, and if possible, get the nice framing (in HTML export) that comes from the EXAMPLE environment:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
some stuff that goes on and on forever right off the edge of any page or browser frame 443okkfq3jg0jg
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Unfortunately, as in Markdown here, wrapping is lost in a verbatim environment.

I would most like to just turn on wrapping within this environment. If that doesn't work, I at least want the ability to place just a delimited block in a monospace font (so that I can get the wrapping from the plain text). How can I achieve one or both of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTML export, you can use your own block names which will export as a `div` element with the block name as a class:

```
#+begin_monoblock
This is some text.
#+end_monoblock
```

Now you can add your format 2 ways:

1: by adding a CSS style definition for all such blocks at the top of your org document

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>.monoblock {font-family:courier;}</style>

... other things

#+begin_monoblock
This is some text.
#+end_monoblock
```

2: by adding style or other HTML attributes individually to each block:

```
#+attr_html: :style font-family:courier;
#+begin_monoblock
This is some text.
#+end_monoblock
```

Or, a combination of both, with some common style for all blocks, plus extra style individually.

Comment: Where is this documented? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't really well documented. If you look at the code for `org-html-special-block` in ox-html.el, you can verify that that's how it works; and the basic documentation for blocks is https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Greater_Blocks